# Error on execute and print the SQL query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using this stored procedure but it's causing an error.

Query is

```
declare @min int
declare @mnt int
declare @query varchar(MAx)
declare @finmnth int
declare @divid int
declare @finyear nvarchar(max)

set @divid = 0
set @finmnth = 6
set @finyear = '2014-15'

begin

    if @finmnth = 3 or @finmnth = 2 or @finmnth = 1
       set @min = 13
    else
       set @min = @finmnth

    Set @query = 'select 
                  /* Cummulative Progress */
                      isNull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), SUM(case when month between 4 and '+cast(@finmnth AS varchar)+' and mpryear='+cast(@finyear as nvarchar)+' then (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 else 0 end),2),0) as CUTMTot
                 from 
                     MPR 
                 where 
                     (division = '+cast(@Divid as varchar)+' OR '+cast(@Divid as varchar)+' = 0)'
end 

exec(@query)
```

Error is

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2013-14' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You miss additional quotes around `@finyear` variable. It is a good idea to print out your statement in such situations: `PRINT @query`. You will see how your statement looks like.

```
DECLARE @min INT
DECLARE @mnt INT
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @finmnth INT
DECLARE @divid INT
DECLARE @finyear NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @divid = 0
SET @finmnth = 6
SET @finyear = '2014-15'

BEGIN

    IF @finmnth = 3
        OR @finmnth = 2
        OR @finmnth = 1
        SET @min = 13
    ELSE
        SET @min = @finmnth

    SET @query = 'select 
                  /* Cummulative Progress */
                      isNull(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), SUM(case when month between 4 and '
        + CAST(@finmnth AS VARCHAR) + ' and mpryear='''/*here*/
        + CAST(@finyear AS NVARCHAR)
        + /*and here*/''' then (IDA+Govt+Benyfe)/100000 else 0 end),2),0) as CUTMTot
                 from 
                     MPR 
                 where 
                     (division = ' + CAST(@Divid AS VARCHAR) + ' OR '
        + CAST(@Divid AS VARCHAR) + ' = 0)'
END 

EXEC(@query)
```